# How to use Google Cloud Billing APIs to calculate usage costs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-billing

How can I use the Google Cloud Billing APIs to retrieve my total expected bill / accumulated bill so far?

Is there an API call that simply returns the cost so far for a certain billing account?

Or alternatively, a combination of calls - one for retrieving the usage data and the other with the prices for the various Google Cloud services - to calculate the costs myself?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you try Google Cloud Billing Report ?
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/03/understand-your-spending-at-a-glance-with-Google-Cloud-Billing-reports-beta.html

Comment: I have not. But from what I can tell, this service is only used through the platform itself, right? What I want to know is whether there are any api calls that I can combine inside my app that will fetch me my billing details.

Comment: May be this new feature could help : https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/05/Better-cost-control-with-Google-Cloud-Billing-programmatic-notifications.html

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is an API to accomplish what you want.

You can control costs, track expenses and create alerts to notify billing administrators following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets)

Based on the comment below Alexandre answer, You can get programmatic budget notifications using Google Cloud Billing API setting up budget notifications as described in [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify).

I suggest you to start trying the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/requests), which performs simpler API calls.