# Google cloud billing API, grab cost for current month

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-billing

I'm currently building an admin dashboard, using flask, for an online service that's running on GKE.

I want to show how large of a bill the service has racked up since the beginning of the month. I've looked into the Google Cloud billing API, but it's a bloody jungle and I can't seem to find any way to retrieve the data I want.

I assume it should be possible but I can't figure out how.
Can anybody more experienced with Google Cloud APIs help me, preferably with python code-snippets?

I've looked at the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392859/how-to-use-google-cloud-billing-apis-to-calculate-usage-costs) but couldn't really figure out how to use them.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to check spending on google cloud with python?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up using Google's dashboards instead.

Answer (score 6):

The official documentation:

[Get started with the Cloud Billing Budget API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api-overview)

[Cloud Billing Budget API Setup](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api-setup)

[Using the Cloud Billing Budget API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budget-api)

[Cloud Billing Budget Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/budget/libraries)

> Use the Cloud Billing Budget API to:
>
> Create a separate budget for each of your Google Cloud projects so you
>   know which areas of your Google Cloud environment are spending more
>   than expected.
>
> Bulk update all of your budgets after quarterly financial planning.
>
> Integrate with your company's deployment manager to add the creation
>   of budgets to your cloud provisioning workflow.

1. Create a project
2. Enable billing
3. Enable the API (Cloud Budget API, Cloud Billing Budget API)
4. Create a Budget, on the Budget & Alerts, Create Budget, Scope, Amount (
   Last month’s spend), Actions
5. Set up authentication (create a service account, grant the service account the role Billing Account Administrator, download the key.json, set the env variable export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
6. Use the client library [Client for Cloud Billing Budget API](https://googleapis.dev/python/billingbudgets/latest/gapic/v1beta1/api.html)

   ```
   from google.cloud import billing_budgets_v1beta1
   client = billing_budgets_v1beta1.BudgetServiceClient()

   #get all the budgets
   parent = client.billing_account_path([BILLING_ACCOUNT])
   for element in client.list_budgets(parent):
      print(element)
      pass

   #for a specific budget
   name = client.budget_path('[BILLING_ACCOUNT]', '[BUDGET]')
   response = client.get_budget(name)

   #The output should be in the form
   ```

   ````
   display_name: "billing-budget"
   budget_filter {
   projects: "projects/"
   credit_types_treatment: 
   }
   amount {
   last_period_amount {
   }
   }
   threshold_rules {
   threshold_percent: 0.5
   spend_basis: CURRENT_SPEND
   }
   threshold_rules {
   threshold_percent: 0.9
   spend_basis: CURRENT_SPEND
   }
   threshold_rules {
   threshold_percent: 1.0
   spend_basis: CURRENT_SPEND
   }
   all_updates_rule {
   }
   etag: "" ```
   ````

## EDIT:

I checked the `gcloud alpha billing` command and I can see only the options :

```
    1. accounts(describe, get-iam-policy, list, projects(describe, link, list, unlink))

    2. budgets(create, delete, describe, list, update) 

    3. projects(describe, link, list, unlink). These are the API that you can call.
```

There is no API for getting current spending to my understanding. You can export billing to BigQuery or to a file(this is deprecated) and do your analysis.

Comment: I'm able to get the output you're listing, but how do I get the current spending?

Comment: Well that sucks. Thank you for your time and effort though.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please mark it as accepted for greater visibility for the community.

Comment: While it did help me understand the billing API better, it did not solve my problem. I therefore think it would be misleading to accept the answer.